# ~1 Year old Avocado tree drooping leaves after repotting

Tags: watering, soil, avocado, repotting

Hi recently I decided to move my avocado tree to a different pot because it suddenly stopped growing new leaves and the leaf tips had started to brown a bit.  I believe I had watered a little too much as there was excess water at the bottom even though there were drain holes so that was one problem that I tried to solve.  I rinsed the roots and tried to remove all of the bad roots as well as tossed the old soil.  I did lose half of the avocado seed during this process.. not sure if that affects anything.

But after I moved it to the new pot with new soil, the very next morning the leaves suddenly drooped and I noticed I definitely didn't water enough as a good portion of the soil was dry.  So I have thoroughly watered it and believe there isn't too much water in the new pot.  The only problem now is that the leaves are still drooping (it has been ~2 days since) and I am worried that I may have killed my avocado tree.

Can someone help take a look?  Here are some pictures of the avocado tree currently...

Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your pot draining? They hate wet feet.... Also what is soil ph? Water ph?
They are also very sensitive to salt build up in soil from watering and feeding.

Answer (score 1):

The drooping is probably a temporary response to the messing with the roots that you speak of. Avocado, unlike many tropical plants, generates large soft leaves that are able to transpire very rapidly. When losing moisture faster than it can be replaced the defensive action is to droop and thereby try to reduce water loss. The pot, even though it appears too small for the large plant it is supporting, is probably large enough for the root but the plant cannot pull enough water up fast enough to replace the loss. Two things: reduce air flow over the leaves and ensure air humidity is adequate. Maybe your air humidity needs to be boosted; try spritzing the leaves as the plant recovers from the root disturbance, and consider a larger pot not necessarily for immediate root space but as a buffer for water availability once the roots have recovered from the "maintenance".

Answer (score 0):

That discoloration is absolutely minimal, the drooping is usually a sign of lack of water not the other way around, but you never know.  Your plant looks better than half of my seedlings at the moment, but I have so many of them they tend to get neglected